# Is there a Chrome extension to solve the accented characters wrong encoding issue?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, database, encoding

By the "accented char wrong encoding issue" I mean the problem that sometimes on blogs "é" become "Ã©", and similar problem for other accented chars.

I knew that one of the reasons is some wrong setting of DB_CHARSET of the database. However I'm thinking, is there a Chrome extension that solves the problem from the client side. For example it may "detects" bad character combinations like "Ã©", and then, either simply replace it by "é", or just do some encoding and decoding like the following:

If the text is

> L'hypothÃ¨se de Riemann, aprÃ¨s qu'on eut perdu l'espoir de la dÃ©montrer par les mÃ©thodes de la thÃ©orie des fonctions, nous apparaÃ®t aujourd'hui sous un jour nouveau, qui la montre insÃ©parable de la conjecture d'Artin sur les fonctions L, ces deux problÃ¨mes Ã©tant deux aspects d'une mÃªme question arithmÃ©tico-algÃ©brique, oÃ¹ l'Ã©tude simultanÃ©e de toutes les extensions cyclotomiques d'un corps de nombres donnÃ© jouera sans doute le rÃ´le dÃ©cisif.

then by doing `.encode("Windows-1252").decode("utf-8")` it becomes

> L'hypothèse de Riemann, après qu'on eut perdu l'espoir de la démontrer par les méthodes de la théorie des fonctions, nous apparaît aujourd'hui sous un jour nouveau, qui la montre inséparable de la conjecture d'Artin sur les fonctions L, ces deux problèmes étant deux aspects d'une même question arithmético-algébrique, où l'étude simultanée de toutes les extensions cyclotomiques d'un corps de nombres donné jouera sans doute le rôle décisif.

Comment: Not sure about an extension but you can click the menu icon on the right side of the adress bar, then select "More Tools" then "Eoncoding", in there you can change the encoding used to view your pages

Comment: It certainly a server side problem. Namely the server saved the information in one encoding and sent it in another. I'm wondering if there is a way to detect this and solve it from client side. If you don't get what I'm saying, search for `ã© instead of é`